# Swift: Incorrect use of UIRefreshControl - unrecognized selector

Tags: uitableview, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have two table views, with the idea about implement the Pull to Refresh in both independently.

First I did this:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refersh")
refreshControl.addTarget(self.tableView1, action:"refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
refreshControl.addTarget(self.tableView2, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
self.tableView1.addSubview(refreshControl)
self.tableView2.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

However, during run time execution the error about unrecognized selector appeared:

```
[UITableView refresh:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: What does your `refresh()` function look like?

Comment: Just the update of the data in the tables: func refresh(sender: AnyObject) { .... } It's working with the answer I gave, the problem was not the sender in the funciton, was the "self.tableView{1,2}" insted of just "self"

Comment: Yeah, should be `self`, but also there's no need to wrap `"refresh:"` in Selector(), it's unnecessary in swift

Comment: I see, so should I only need: action: "refresh:"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing this line:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Only one target "pointing" to self.

I hope it helps.

Cheers